# Trying to do Unwind and Merge on the same command On Neo4J C# Client

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4jclient

I am trying to create a batch of nodes from list but I want to make sure those nodes are not already exists in the neo4j db, 
I manage to do it on a single node but I also want to enable it for batch of nodes
I have tried this command:

```
    graphClient.Cypher
        .Unwind(NodesList, "singleNode")
        .Merge("(node:Node {Id : {innerNode}.Id})")
        .OnCreate()
        .Set("innerNode= singleNode")
        .WithParams("innerNode")
        .ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

and I am getting a error of "Parameter Count Mismatch"

- I am still new to Neo4J and I havn't found any one with the same problem at c# language

Thanks a lot from advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that `NodesList` is a list of the nodes you're wanting to `MERGE` - in essence, you need to drop the `innerNode` from your query, and use the `singleNode` you're passing in from the `UNWIND`:

```
graphClient.Cypher
    .Unwind(NodesList, "singleNode")
    .Merge("(node:Node {Id : singleNode.Id})")
    .OnCreate()
    .Set("node = singleNode")
    .ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

This should get you there